# How can I fix the total values of pivot tables in Odoo 8?

Tags: javascript, python-2.7, odoo, pivot-table, odoo-8

I am taking a look through the interface to the pivot tables in *Reporting > Accounting > Entries analysis*, and I am realizing that the total row at the top of the pivot table is wrong.

I have installed `account` and the `multi_company` module, and I have three companies, each one with their own accounting moves. What I am checking is that the total row is giving the sum of the moves of one of the three companies (it seems that the selected company is random), instead of giving the sum of the values of the column. If I group only by company, I can see this fact clearly:

[image: Multi-company pivot table]

Take a look at the screenshot. For example, at the column of the period *01/2017*. The total is only giving the total of the entries of the
*Company B*, which is 1613010.25, while it should be 1705087.86, the sum of 1613010.25 plus 92077.61. The problem is the same in each period, but the value shown in the total is random, sometimes the one of *Company A*, sometimes the one of the *Company B* and sometimes the one of the *Company C*.

I do not know if this pivot table is following a logical behaviour, but I would like to know what is the reason of these total values.

I was looking everywhere to modify that behaviour and show the actual total values, and I got to *pivot.js*, in *web_graph* module. But I am not able to find where are these total values being computed.

Can anyone help me with this or does anyone know the reason of why the total values are showing the total of a random company instead of all?

Comment: Very weird, try to look into https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8.0/addons/account/report/account_entries_report.py and of course try to debug `read_group()`. That's where the totals are calculated.